# Ethernet does not work with Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: networking, server, ethernet

I want to install some packages via Ethernet, but it does not seem to be working. I want a DHCP connection.

Here is what I tried:

`ifconfig` (net-tools was installed via usb)

Which only gives LoopBack

Trying to modify the `etc/network/interfaces` file using `cat etc/network/interfaces`:

cat: /etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory

I tried looking in the `etc/network` folder only to find that there are only 3 files:

if-post-down.d if-pre-up.d and if-up.d

Looking at /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml it shows this:

```
  network:
        ethernets: {}
         version: 2
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: @user535733 I have looked in the `/etc/netplan` to find a file called 00-installer-config.yaml.  Is this it? I have tried looking at it in vi.

Comment: @user535733 I would like to try both, but for now I will try DHCP. I will edit the question to show the .yaml file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Netplan is the tool for configuring networks now.

- It's very easy to use, and [here's whole page full of examples](https://netplan.io/examples).

**Step 1**. Use `ip addr` to locate your **interface name**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
```

- Here, you can see that my ethernet interface is named **enp3s0**.

**Step 2**. Modify the netplan YAML file. Here's an easy example:

- This requires a text editor and sudo, of course.
- Tip: Proper indentation is critical, Use spaces, NOT tabs.

  ```
  # This is a comment line - lines starting with # are ignored.
  network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
      enp3s0:           # Here is where that interface name goes!
        dhcp4: true
  ```

**Step 3**: Run `sudo netplan apply`. Netplan will parse and apply the new config, including requesting a new dhcp address.

After this, your network should be up.

- This config is for a server without GUI (networkd) using a wired ethernet (enp3s0) and dhcp. If you need a different configuration, check that [page full of examples](https://netplan.io/examples). What you want is probably in there.