# Upgraded to 22.04.01, DNS didn't work, tried to fix, now Ethernet doesn't work

Tags: networking, dns, ethernet, systemd, netplan

I recently upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04.01 on both my laptop (uses WiFi) and my desktop (uses Ethernet) via Ubuntu's standard update process (they prompted me to upgrade and I clicked OK). Networking on the laptop with 22.04.01 has no issues. Both machines dual boot to Windows 10; the laptop works fine on WiFi while the desktop works fine on Ethernet. However, the desktop running Ubuntu 22.04.01 was not connecting properly to the internet due to some kind of DNS error; pinging google.com failed but pinging 8.8.8.8 worked fine.

Websearching indicated I could edit /etc/resolv.conf to add a DNS address like 9.9.9.9 in place of 127.0.0.53. That worked temporarily but after reboot it appears systemd had changed it back to 127.0.0.53 and the DNS no longer worked. This was not too surprising since resolv.conf itself says it's managed by systemd and also says "Do not edit".

I found [elsewhere](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012641/dns-set-to-systemds-127-0-0-53-how-to-change-permanently) (see intelfx's response) that I could instead update /etc/systemd/resolved.conf to include a DNS address. That didn't work either. Neither did updating the DNS in the Ubuntu settings GUI ([as shown here](https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-set-dns-nameserver-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy/)). However, that same link also included instructions on setting the DNS using netplan. I tried editing /etc/netplan/01-network-manager.yaml according to those instructions, but that didn't work either.

Somehow (probably when messing with netplan) I deactivated my ethernet (ping no longer worked whether pinging 8.8.8.8 or google.com).
`sudo lshw -C network` gives:

```
*-network DISABLED
    description: Ethernet interface
    product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
    logical name: enp4s0
    version: 0c
    serial: 78:24:af:34:3e:04
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33 MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.0-47-generic latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
    resources: irq:17 iport:d000(size=256) memory:fe900000-fe900fff memory:f0300000-f0303fff
```

Also, in the Settings GUI under Network, there is no longer an entry for 'Wired' like there used to be; it just has 'VPN' and 'Network Proxy'. On the upper right of the screen near the power button there's no longer an icon for my wired connection either.

Somewhere else I found a suggestion to reactivate Ethernet via `sudo nmcli networking off` followed by `sudo nmcli networking on`; that did no good.

So, I would appreciate any help with this:

1. How do I reactivate my ethernet?
2. How do I get my desktop to properly use a DNS on Ubuntu 22.04.01? And why was it broken in the first place, right after my upgrade?

I am no command line expert, nor do I know much about how Ubuntu handles networking, but I can follow instructions reasonably well.

Adding info requested in comments:

/etc/network/interfaces does not exist. `ls` within /etc/network gives these directories:

```
if-down.d  if-post-down.d  if-pre-up.d  if-up.d
```

/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml is only 3 lines; I previously extended it based on [these instructions](https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-set-dns-nameserver-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy/) and ran `sudo netplan try` and `sudo netplan apply` but after that didn't fix my DNS issue I reverted it back to its original form by removing the lines I added and running `sudo netplan try` and `sudo netplan apply` again:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system.
network:
  version: 2
```

UPDATE AND SOLUTION:

Thanks, @thomas-ward, for solving my ethernet problem - after adding the 4th line to my YAML file, running `sudo netplan apply`, and rebooting, that problem was fixed.

My DNS problem is also solved; after further searching I found [Ethernet does not work with Ubuntu Server 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240325/ethernet-does-not-work-with-ubuntu-server-20-04?rq=1) which led me to https://netplan.io/examples . I modified my YAML file in `/etc/netplan` according to the 'Using DHCP and static addressing' example, ran `sudo netplan try`, accepted the changes, and it worked, persisting after reboot (substitute your own interface name for enp3s0, and spacing is important):

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
```

Issue [Hostnames cannot be resolved after upgrading to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406630/hostnames-cannot-be-resolved-after-upgrading-to-22-04) was also helpful (per @C0rn3j, "This seems to be caused by Ubuntu 22.04 expecting to be configured via netplan. Netplan configuration is created on a fresh install, but if you've an upgraded system, the necessary configurations are not present.")

Comment: Your **e**thernet layer seems to be working fine. Search this site with "[dns] [22.04]".

Comment: Please provide the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` Thanks.

Comment: Also provide the complete contents of all your netplan YAML.

Comment: Please make sure you EDIT and add the info to the question. Do not reply with a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a broken configuration.  If you want to use Network Manager then `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` needs to look like this:

```yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

You need a `renderer` line to tell the system that Network Manager is in control.  And that seems to be missing in your environment.  Update your file accordingly with the example I posted (from a clean 22.04 system!) and then reboot.  See if that lets you control your ethernet card and such again.